# html JavaScript is not showing image as new page loads

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, image

I have a html page that shows a animated processing image while I wait for it to redirect to new page.

For some reason when the page starts the redirect the animation stops.

The purpose of this is to make a request to a PHP script and once the PHP script has completed it's processes the HTML and the page will redirect.

Can you provide help to allow the processing animated image to continue to show it's animation while I am waiting for the redirect to complete.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html { 
  background: url(processing.gif) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
</style>

<body>
<script>
         setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.href = 'processing.php';
         }, 1000);
      </script>
<div class="bg"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you redirect, any loading of data including images are stopped. Use Ajax instead

Comment: When the next page starts to load, you really have no control over it....

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you try to make the animation to continue until the page finish to upload. you can do it by PHP code, by trying to cash the loading time and then you can disable the animation.

I tried something like this:

```
<?php

$time_start = microtime(true); 


$time_end = microtime(true);

//dividing with 60 will give the execution time in minutes otherwise seconds
$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start)/60;

echo 'The process took ' . $execution_time. ' mintues ';

?>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #bg{ 
     background: url(processing.gif) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
    }
</style>
<script>
         setTimeout(function(){
            var stop = document.getElementById("bg").style.background="0"; //disable the background
         }, <?php echo intval($execution_time) ?>); // echo the int value that took to the process
      </script>
</head>

<body id="bg">



</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

By start of redirect , any process in current page will be stopping so you can't continue animation of gif. my suggestion is that increase time of your `setTimeout`.